# eesen-transcriber - Adding Technical Words to Dictionary

Tags: speech-recognition, speech-to-text, transcription

I'm using the [srvk/eesen-transcriber](https://github.com/srvk/eesen-transcriber) repository to transcribe some audio files and I've got everything up and running as expected on my Vagrant virtual machine.

I'd like to be able to transcribe very technical audio recordings with words like Linux, Laravel, or MySQL, which don't get transcribed very well. How would I go about (easily) adding these words to the transcription software so that they are successfully recognized when spoken?

### UPDATE

I've attempted to follow the directions suggested to me by Nikolay Shmyrev found here:

http://speechkitchen.org/kaldi-language-model-building/

I can successfully run the `run_adapt.sh` script after adding new vocab to `newwords.txt`, but when I try to use the updated language model to transcribe the audio file with the new vocab, it doesn't recognize the new vocab.

Here is a video of my attempt to follow the directions on how to adapt the language model:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?edit=vd&v=-Zn9_y56R4c

Comment: did you somehow solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to adapt the language model. Documentation is here:

http://speechkitchen.org/kaldi-language-model-building/

Comment: Thank you for your response! I've tried following the directions found on the link you provided, but I still can't seem to get it to recognize the new vocab. I've edited my original question to show what I've attempted. Any other advice?

Comment: Automatic pronunciation generation might not work for abbreviations like MYSQL, you'll have to add them to the dictionary manually too. You can share your files over dropbox, I'll take a look.